# Detect RAM type (DDR2/3/4)

Tags: c, linux, ram

In [dmidecode](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode) utility we use reading [SMBIOS](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios) table, located at `/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/` to determine properties of memory, e.g. type. It requeres knowledge of SMBIOS structure, handles, offsets etc.

Is there some system-independent interface in Linux/POSIX to do that from C application? I think it would be extremely unpleasant if software stop working because of changes in future SMBIOS formats.

Comment: The best way is to see his it's done in dmidecode. I'm not sure if there any better way

Comment: As for me, parsing firmware tables is a very unreliable way.
This might stop working after 4-5 years of support and it would be very hard to detect the reason. However, it seems there are really no alternatives

Comment: @YuriS.Cherkasov Unfortunately this is the only or at least there's no "better way", or more "portable" way. C/POSIX or any standard that is in anyway cross-OS portable, does not have language level support for stuff as low level as memory type (how could C possibly know that?). What's worse is that there's no instruction level support either. So you end up with only operating system specific support. And once you end-up at this level, you have to deal with possible future changes. It's just not meant to be "portable" or "future proof"

Comment: Problem is, in 4-5 years your software might not be able to detect the MRAM, ReRAM or whatever technology might be used form main-memory. You will be busted one way or the other. If yxou want to go that deep into system details, you have to go that deep into system information. The more interesting question is: what do you want to accomplish **actually**? Why do you want to know which memory technology is used? This is definitively nothing a normal program should care about.